# Python ctypes bitfield Windows vs. Linux

Tags: python, c++, linux, windows, ubuntu

I am running into an OS dependent issue with a relatively simple bitfield defined in Python ctype. The bitfield runs well under Windows 7 x64, yet fails in Ubuntu 12.04 x64. Both OS are using Python 2.7 interpreter.

Attached code highlights my problem. If my bitfields is defined using c_uint, it fails in Ubuntu. If I switched it over to c_ushort, it works as expected. Windows appears to work on either definition.

In Windows, the following code outputs:

```
1 1 3 1 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0
1 1 3 1 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0
```

In Linux, the following code outputs:

```
0 1 0 1 0 7 0 9 0 12 0 13 14 15 0
1 1 3 1 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0
```

I have [re-written this bitfield](http://pastebin.com/n0a84Pbp) in C++ under Ubuntu/GCC 4 and Win/MSVC9, and C++ is fine with both definition. So I concluded this is a Python specific issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: Per [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275418/markku-k)'s suggestion, it appears to be a Python bug. So I filed a bug against Python bug tracker at http://bugs.python.org/issue20629

```
import ctypes
class BitField1(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
    ('a', ctypes.c_uint, 3),
    ('b', ctypes.c_uint, 1),
    ('c', ctypes.c_uint, 3),
    ('d', ctypes.c_uint, 1),
    ('f', ctypes.c_uint, 8),
    ('g', ctypes.c_uint, 16),
    ('h', ctypes.c_uint, 16),
    ('i', ctypes.c_uint, 16),
    ('j', ctypes.c_uint, 8),
    ('k', ctypes.c_uint, 8),
    ('l', ctypes.c_uint, 8),
    ('m', ctypes.c_uint, 8),
    ('n', ctypes.c_ulonglong, 56),    
    ('o', ctypes.c_ulonglong, 4),
    ('p', ctypes.c_ulonglong, 4)
    ]

class BitField1U(ctypes.Union):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("fields", BitField1), 
        ("raw_bytes", ctypes.c_ubyte * 20)]

class BitField2(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
    ('a', ctypes.c_ushort, 3),
    ('b', ctypes.c_ushort, 1),
    ('c', ctypes.c_ushort, 3),
    ('d', ctypes.c_ushort, 1),
    ('f', ctypes.c_ushort, 8),
    ('g', ctypes.c_ushort, 16),
    ('h', ctypes.c_ushort, 16),
    ('i', ctypes.c_ushort, 16),
    ('j', ctypes.c_ushort, 8),
    ('k', ctypes.c_ushort, 8),
    ('l', ctypes.c_ushort, 8),
    ('m', ctypes.c_ushort, 8),
    ('n', ctypes.c_ulonglong, 56),    
    ('o', ctypes.c_ulonglong, 4),
    ('p', ctypes.c_ulonglong, 4)
    ]

class BitField2U(ctypes.Union):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("fields", BitField2), 
        ("raw_bytes", ctypes.c_ubyte * 20)]

def setup(fields) :
    fields.a = 1
    fields.b = 1
    fields.c = 3
    fields.d = 1
    fields.f = 6
    fields.g = 7
    fields.h = 8
    fields.i = 9
    fields.j = 10
    fields.k = 11
    fields.l = 12
    fields.m = 13
    fields.n = 14
    fields.o = 15
    fields.p = 16

def printFields(fields) :
    print(fields.a),
    print(fields.b),
    print(fields.c),
    print(fields.d),
    print(fields.f),
    print(fields.g),
    print(fields.h),
    print(fields.i),
    print(fields.j),
    print(fields.k),
    print(fields.l),
    print(fields.m),
    print(fields.n),
    print(fields.o),
    print(fields.p)

b1 = BitField1U()
b2 = BitField2U()
setup(b1.fields)
setup(b2.fields)
printFields(b1.fields)
printFields(b2.fields)
```

Comment: why wouldnt you simply use python ints? and apply bitmasks? then it will definately be the same

Comment: There seems to be a problem with ctypes.BigEndianStructure. If you change BitField1 to inherit from just plain ctypes.Structure, I think you will get better results. Not sure why at this point.

Comment: I am doing memory overlay to decode a bytearray. That's why in the code, there are unions with a c_ubyte type.

Comment: Markku K, you are right. By changing it to ctypes.Structure, the assignment works. However, I am overlaying the bitfield on top of memory that is in big endian. I "think" I need to use BigEndianStructure.

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug in ctypes. You can reproduce this odd behavior with just fields 'a' and 'b' of your BigEndianStruct. Just look at what happens to the "raw_bytes" part of your union if you set b1.fields.a = 1 *twice*. It looks like each time you set a value, the whole underlying uint is byte-swapped -- so the 'a' value you set the first time gets copied to the first bit of the 4th byte at the beginning of the second time you set it.

Comment: You are right. Simplify setting b1.fields.a twice performs some sort of copy + byte-swap in Ubuntu. In Windows, I don't see this behavior.

Comment: The question has a long time but does anybody knows whether this problem has been solved? I am having the same problem in Python 3.8.